# Valdiation Formula Broken

Tags: formula, picklist, validation-rule, isblank

The scenario for the validation rule is:
-if one lookup field is empty, then check that other n fields are not empty
(if a lookup is empty, then make sure that the fields that will be used to create the new object are filled with something)

It should be as easy as this:

```
AND(
    ISNULL(MyLookup__c),
    OR(
        ISBLANK(MyText__c),
        ISBLANK(MyText2__c),
        ISBLANK(MyText3__c),
        ISBLANK(TEXT(MyPicklist__c)),
        ISBLANK(TEXT(MyPicklist2__c)),
        ISBLANK(TEXT(MyPicklist3__c))
    )
)
```

EDIT:
MyText__c and MyText2__c are text fields, MyText3__c is Long Text.. if I remove the long text and the picklists the condition works as expected.. :s

EDIT2:
this is the code I've used in a trigger to perform the check and it works as expected:

```
 if(
      r.MyLookup__c==null && (
           r.MyText__c==null ||
           r.MyText2__c==null ||
           r.MyText3__c==null ||
           r.MyPicklist__c==null ||
           r.MyPicklist2__c==null ||
           r.MyPicklist3__c==null
      )
 ){
      r.addError('Fill the data to...blabla');

 }
```

Comment: if lookup is empty then all fields should be filled ?

Comment: Yes, I think though there is something wrong with LongText.. please don't tell me that ISBLANK won't work on Long Text fields...

Comment: try to use TRIM the field and check length == 0

Comment: I tried but still won't work, I solved it with code and the same logic, but I can't understand what is wrong with the formula

Comment: so you need AND condition instead OR so it will check for all the field is null or not

Comment: the OR condition is true when at least one of the ISBLANK is true, which is what I want, the error fires on true. If all fields are filled: all ISBLANK conditions are false and the overall OR is false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39284/discussion-between-ratan-and-t-rossi).

Comment: Could you do a LEN of the long text and the picklist?

Comment: I tried that with Ratan but it won't work on longtext anyway

Comment: You might upvote [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrhEAAS)

Comment: Also, look in the comments at Eva Mave Ng's suggestion. Maybe that could work? I know it seems like a long work around...

Comment: It's quiet interesting i don't know why Len is not working with long text fields.Really nice question I'm working on it. @T. Rossi

Comment: It looks like Long Text fields are not supported in formula fields, but THEY ARE in validation formulas (I just tested). Could it be that you have some of picklist fields are populated with a default value (e.g. 'N/A' or '--') ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achive that with a validation rule or a before trigger is you want a validation rule you need change the

```
ISNULL(MyLookup__c) to ISBLANK(MyLookup__c).
```

If you want to use a trigger I recomend you that you use the next example.

```
if( String.isBlank(r.MyLookup__c) && (
  String.isBlank(r.MyText__c) ||
  String.isBlank(r.MyText2__c) ||
  String.isBlank(r.MyText3__c) ||
  String.isBlank(r.MyPicklist__c) ||
  String.isBlank(r.MyPicklist2__c) ||
  String.isBlank(r.MyPicklist3__c)
)){
  r.addError('Fill the data to...blabla');
}
```

All this is because the Ids are String fields and in the string null value   is diferente a blank value.

Comment: Thx for the code suggestion, the lookup part is working properly I can use ISBLANK if it's a best practice, but it was not the encountered problem. The problem is what ISBLANK id doing on longtext fields, I can't figure it out, looks like it's always false.

Comment: then use the isblank in the trigger because the long text could be empty or be a space chain

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.
Hope this help

```
AND(ISBLANK(MyLookup__c),



    OR(

        NOT(ISBLANK(MyText__c)),

        NOT(ISBLANK(MyText2__c)),

        NOT(ISBLANK(MyText3__c)),

        NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(MyPicklist__c))),

        NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(MyPicklist2__c))),

        NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(MyPicklist3__c)))
   )
)
```

Comment: Ankit -- when posting code/formulas - please format the code using the `{}` toolbar button

Comment: Sure Ratan,Noted

Comment: Ankit : Ratan kindly formatted this for you

Answer (score -1):

I think Mr Frodo is right here.
Your formula returns true if the lookup is null OR ANY of tested fields are not blank.   I think you want to test that all the the fields to be filled in. You need to use an AND for that.  Try this...

```
OR(
    ISNULL(MyLookup__c),
    AND(
        NOT(ISBLANK(MyText__c)),
        NOT(ISBLANK(MyText2__c)),
        NOT(ISBLANK(MyText3__c)),
        NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(MyPicklist__c))),
        NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(MyPicklist2__c))),
        NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(MyPicklist3__c)))
   )
)
```

Comment: say my lookup is empy, no matter what I do in the other fields, I'll always get the error OR(true, anything) = true... :/ and once again: AND (NOT(A), NOT(B),..) = OR(A, B, C) ....